# Will a locksmith prefer to install a handle on a door that is hung or laying flat on horses?

Tags: doors, doorknob

I have several hardwood doors that will need to have door handles and latches installed. Currently the doors are unhung and laying on saw horses (for sanding and painting).

Will the locksmith prefer to install the handles with the doors laying horizontal like this, or will he prefer that the doors be hung?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would vastly prefer to do them hung.

As far as just attaching the hardware, that job is a cakewalk when the door is hung.  Doing it while the door is on sawhorses only creates a handling problem; the doorknob will be awkward.

If holes need to be drilled for the knob, latch and strike, then trying to do that separately using measurements would be *insane*. 95% chance you'd mount the carefully measured door, and by golly, they'd be misaligned.

Doing the work hung doesn't add enough difficulty to be worth the trouble it will cause for fitment.